# page not found errors for javascript following upgrade to 4.6.13 from 4.6.10

Tags: upgrade

Civicrm version is on Drupal 7.  Drupal was upgraded first to version 7.4.3.  Paths for javascript and css files are not found.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: Further information.  I was able upgrade to 4.6.15, but when trying to go to version 4.7.6, I get the page not found errors for javascript files.

Comment: Additional information.  Also fails from 4.6.15 to 4.7.0.  Repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ensured that CiviCRM paths are set correctly? In the Civi menubar go to *Administer -> System Settings -> Directories* and ensure it matches what's in *Administer -> System Settings -> Resource URLs*

Comment: Yes, the paths are set correctly.  Only oddity is image files are in sites/default/files/pictures/??

Comment: Update on error.  Getting CiviCRM_API13_Exception 'Moneris is not a valid option for field payment_processor_type_id'  Error Code- 2001-  Moneris is not a valid option for field payment_processor_type_id